# Setting second dimension of vector of vectors to zero (C++)

Tags: c++, stdvector, multidimensional-array

There is a vector of vectors:

```
std::vector <std::vector <float> > VoV;
VoV.resize(num);   // num is determined at run-time
for (int i=0; i<num; ++i) {

    VoV[i].resize(3);   // initializing to zero
}
```

I want to set all three elements to zero after some manipulation. I mean, I know initially they will be set to zero however, their values will change after a while and I want to set them all zero again. So, is the following correct? Is it efficient and is there a better way?

```
std::fill(VoV.begin(), VoV.end(), 0.f);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways you can set all of the data to zero. The simplest is perhaps:

```
VoV = std::vector<std::vector<float> >(num, std::vector<float>(3, 0.));
```

Or,

```
std::fill(VoV.begin(), VoV.end(), std::vector<float>(3, 0.));
```

Or,

```
for(std::vector<float>& v : VoV)
  std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.);
```

Or even:

```
for(auto& v : Vov)
  for(auto& f : v)
    f = 0;
```

<sub>Note: I haven't tested any of these.</sub>

Comment: Worth noting that the first requires reallocation of all elements in both dimensions.

Comment: Noted. And the 2nd requires reallocation of the component vectors. Neither the 3rd nor 4th require any reallocation.

Comment: So, 3rd and 4th methods should be faster?

Comment: @Shibli That the 3rd and 4rth go faster is my naïve belief. As with anything related to speed, if it matters to you, test it yourself.

Comment: @Rob: 3rd one gives, `reference variable 'v' requires initializer`

Comment: @Shibli - The final two require C++11 features. It works with GCC 4.6.1 with the command `g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Werror -pedantic x.cc`.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You have vector of vector, so to fill it you need a vector. In addition to Rob's answer, to gain better performance do it in loop (preserving your syntax/style):

```
for (int i=0; i<num; ++i) {
    VoV[i].fill(VoV[i].begin(), VoV[i].end(), 0.f);   // initializing to zero
}
```

In this case you'll avoid memory allocation reusing existing vectors.